# BroadcastReceiver makes animations lag

Tags: android, android-service, android-animation, android-mediaplayer, android-broadcast

I have a **MediaPlayer running in a Service**. The **service sends a broadcast to the activity** with the current duration of the song every 250ms to update a SeekBar in the activity.

```
seekIntent = new Intent("com.someaction"); 

private Runnable sendUpdateToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        LogMediaPosition();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 250);
    }
};

private void LogMediaPosition()
{
    mediaPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mediaMax = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    seekIntent.putExtra("counter", mediaPosition);
    seekIntent.putExtra("mediamax", mediaMax);
    sendBroadcast(seekIntent);
}
```

and **in the activity**

`registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.someaction"));`

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        updateUI(intent);
    }       
};

private void updateUI(Intent intent)
{
    int seekProgress = intent.getIntExtra("counter", 0);
    int seekMax = intent.getIntExtra("mediamax", 0);

    songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(utils.millisecondsToTimer(seekProgress));
    songProgressBar.setMax(seekMax);
    songProgressBar.setProgress(seekProgress);
}
```

The activity also has a simple **TranslateAnimation**.

```
TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
translate.setDuration(500);
translate.setFillAfter(true);
translate.setFillEnabled(true);
btnName.startAnimation(translate);
```

When the receiver is registered, there is a very slight but noticeable lag in the TranslateAnimation. But if I comment out the registerReceiver() line in the activity, i.e., not letting the receiver to register thus not updating the SeekBar, the TranslateAnimation runs perfectly smooth.

Any suggestion, how could this be resolved to get smooth animation even after having the receiver registered?

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast receiver runs on the UI thread unless you specifically request it to do so, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29). You should not really be doing a lot of computation in the onReceive() method (and bear in mind the 10 sec time limit).

You should maybe examine how you're notifying the ProgressBar to update and also examine what you're doing with the TranslateAnimation.

Comment: I also added the code for TranslateAnimation to the question. If you could tell by looking at the code, how can I improve it?